# How can i get substring in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

There is a column.
And it has values like

'/abc/def/ghi/w1.xyz'

'/jkl/mno/r.stuv'

(it's path data and the number of '/'s in each value is not fixed.)

how can i get substring column which has values like

'/abc/def/ghi/'

'/jkl/mno/'

(extracting only the directory part. removing the file part.)

i read about substr(X,Y), substr(X,Y,Z), instr(X,Y).

but it's not easy to apply them because the number of '/'s in each value is not fixed and instr(X,Y) seems to find the first occurrence from the left.

Comment: I don't know if SQLite has a function that can help you. You can use a programming language like Python, PHP, Unix/Windows utilities to extract data out of SQLite and split it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a recursive [CTE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
create table tablename(col text);
insert into tablename(col) values
('/abc/def/ghi/w1.xyz'),
('/jkl/mno/r.stuv');

with recursive cte(col, pos, rest) as (
  select col, instr(col, '/') pos, substr(col, instr(col, '/') + 1) rest
  from tablename
  union all
  select col, instr(rest, '/'), substr(rest, instr(rest, '/') + 1) 
  from cte 
  where instr(rest, '/') > 0                                        
)  
select col, substr(col, 1, sum(pos)) path
from cte                               
group by col
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUhKGV5EKzmwDyoAFLSEVK/1).
Results:

```
| col                 | path          |
| ------------------- | ------------- |
| /abc/def/ghi/w1.xyz | /abc/def/ghi/ |
| /jkl/mno/r.stuv     | /jkl/mno/     |
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix/Linux environment, you could do something like this (let's take an example).

Let's say `test.db` was your SQLite3 database with a table like so:

```
create table test (dataset text);
insert into test (dataset) values ('/abc/def/ghi/w1.xyz');
insert into test (dataset) values ('/jkl/mno/r.stuv');
```

From command line, you can run:

```
sqlite3 test.db -batch -noheader "select dataset from test"
```

That'll give you this as the output (I know that's not the output you want, but just read on):

```
/abc/def/ghi/w1.xyz
/jkl/mno/r.stuv
```

Explanation

- the `-batch` and `-noheader` switches suppress all output except for the data resulting from the SQL statement
- `sqlite3 test.db -batch -noheader "sql statement"` runs the SQL statement you provided and the output is dumped on the screen (stdout)

## Solution

Now, we'll use `awk` with it to get what you want like so:

```
sqlite3 test.db -batch -noheader "select dataset from test" | awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS="/"} {$NF = ""; print $0}'
```

Result will be:

```
/abc/def/ghi/
/jkl/mno/
```

Crude explanation

- `awk` works on every line output by your sqlite3 command
- the line is split by `/` character with `-F'/'` switch
- since we want the output to contain the delimiters as is, we set the output field separator to be `'/'` as well using `OFS='/'`
- we set number of fields (NF) in a way that the last item is ignored and then we print the rest of the data
- as the other split fields are printed, OFS inserts `/` between those fields

Comment: Thank you. I learned different way from you. I couldn't imagine it. but I have to use only SQL statements. ♡

Comment: That's the beauty of StackOverflow - learning from one another different techniques of computing. User `forpas` is brilliant and that solution of recursive CT was absolutely fantastic.